# Why are these input and text parts on the right side, if they supposed to be on the center?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a problem whit my new project. A login system. I did it from a *youtube video*: https://youtu.be/cxm5bCCa9OA . Everything works perfectly, It just bothers me, that my text is **right-sided** instead of **centered**, but the YouTuber's text is fine. *I think I have the same code.* I think The problem might be with the **form's border** or the **positioning** of my Texts.

My Log in system:[image]

The YouTuber's Log in system:

[image]

My code is also here:

```css
.box {
  top: 80px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  width: 380px;
  height: 420px;
  background: #000000;
  border-radius: 8px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.box::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -50%;
  left: -50%;
  width: 380px;
  height: 420px;
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, transparent, #00d8d6, #00d8d6);
  transform-origin: bottom right;
  animation: animate 6s linear infinite;
}

.box::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -50%;
  left: -50%;
  width: 380px;
  height: 420px;
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, transparent, #00d8d6, #00d8d6);
  transform-origin: bottom right;
  animation: animate 6s linear infinite;
  animation-delay: -3s;
}

@keyframes animate {
  /*colorwave line animation*/
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

.form {
  position: absolute;
  inset: 3px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  background: #343745;
  z-index: 10;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.form h4 {
  color: #7ed6df;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 0.05em;
  font-size: 3em;
  font-style: italic;
}

.inputBox {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  margin-top: 35px;
}

.inputBox input {
  position: relative;
  width: 90%;
  padding: 20px 10px 10px;
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: #535c68;
  font-size: 0.5em;
  letter-spacing: 0.06em;
  z-index: 10;
}

.inputBox span {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  padding: 20px 0px 10px;
  font-size: 0.7em;
  color: #8f8f8f;
  pointer-events: none;
  letter-spacing: 0.03em;
}

.inputBox input:valid~span,
.inputBox input:focus~span {
  color: #7ed6df;
  transform: translateX(0px) translateY(-34px);
  font-size: 0.7em
}

.inputBox i {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background: #7ed6df;
  border-radius: 4px;
  transition: 0.5s;
  pointer-events: none;
  z-index: 9;
}

.inputBox input:valid~i,
.inputBox input:focus~i {
  height: 40px;
}

.loglinks {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.loglinks a {
  margin: 15px;
  font-size: 0.4em;
  color: #8f8f8f;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.loglinks a:hover,
.loglinks a:nth-child(2) {
  color: #7ed6df;
}

input[type="submit"] {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  background: #7ed6df;
  padding: 11px 25px;
  width: 100px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-weight: 600;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type="submit"]:active {
  opacity: 0.8;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Clicker+Script&family=IM+Fell+DW+Pica&family=Playfair+Display+SC:ital@1&family=Yeseva+One&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/f90175d7f9.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<center>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="form">
      <h4>Log In
        <h4>
          <div class="inputBox">
            <input type="text" required="required">
            <span>Username</span>
            <i></i>
          </div>
          <div class="inputBox">
            <input type="password" required="required">
            <span>Password</span>
            <i></i>
          </div>
          <div class="loglinks">
            <a href="#">Forgot Password</a>
            <a href="#">Sign up</a>
          </div>
          <input type="submit" value="Enter">
    </div>
  </div>
</center>
```

Comment: You should include html

Comment: We need to see your HTML as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To center those `input`s you may add a `margin-left` and a `margin-right` of `auto` to `.inputBox`. Or simply change this:

```css
.inputBox {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  margin-top: 35px; /** change this */
}
```

into this:

```css
.inputBox {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 35px auto 0; /** into that */
  /** 
  * the above rule means:
  *   - 35px as margin top
  *   - left and right margins set to "auto" which horizontally centers your ".inputBox"
  *   - 0px as margin bottom
  */
}
```

And here's a live demo (made some changes to your code because you had some tags that were not closed)

```css
.box {
  top: 80px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  width: 380px;
  height: 420px;
  background: #000000;
  border-radius: 8px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.box::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -50%;
  left: -50%;
  width: 380px;
  height: 420px;
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, transparent, #00d8d6, #00d8d6);
  transform-origin: bottom right;
  animation: animate 6s linear infinite;
}

.box::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -50%;
  left: -50%;
  width: 380px;
  height: 420px;
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, transparent, #00d8d6, #00d8d6);
  transform-origin: bottom right;
  animation: animate 6s linear infinite;
  animation-delay: -3s;
}

@keyframes animate {
  /*colorwave line animation*/
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

.form {
  position: absolute;
  inset: 3px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  background: #343745;
  z-index: 10;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.form h4 {
  color: #7ed6df;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 0.05em;
  font-size: 3em;
  font-style: italic;
}

.inputBox {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 35px auto 0;
}

.inputBox input {
  position: relative;
  width: 90%;
  padding: 20px 10px 10px;
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: #535c68;
  font-size: 0.5em;
  letter-spacing: 0.06em;
  z-index: 10;
}

.inputBox span {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  padding: 20px 0px 10px;
  font-size: 0.7em;
  color: #8f8f8f;
  pointer-events: none;
  letter-spacing: 0.03em;
}

.inputBox input:valid~span,
.inputBox input:focus~span {
  color: #7ed6df;
  transform: translateX(0px) translateY(-34px);
  font-size: 0.7em
}

.inputBox i {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background: #7ed6df;
  border-radius: 4px;
  transition: 0.5s;
  pointer-events: none;
  z-index: 9;
}

.inputBox input:valid~i,
.inputBox input:focus~i {
  height: 40px;
}

.loglinks {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.loglinks a {
  margin: 15px;
  font-size: 0.4em;
  color: #8f8f8f;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.loglinks a:hover,
.loglinks a:nth-child(2) {
  color: #7ed6df;
}

input[type="submit"] {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  background: #7ed6df;
  padding: 11px 25px;
  width: 100px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-weight: 600;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type="submit"]:active {
  opacity: 0.8;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Clicker+Script&family=IM+Fell+DW+Pica&family=Playfair+Display+SC:ital@1&family=Yeseva+One&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/f90175d7f9.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="box">
  <div class="form">
    <h4>Log In</h4>
    <div class="inputBox">
      <input type="text" required="required">
      <span>Username</span>
      <i></i>
    </div>
    <div class="inputBox">
      <input type="password" required="required">
      <span>Password</span>
      <i></i>
    </div>
    <div class="loglinks">
      <a href="#">Forgot Password</a>
      <a href="#">Sign up</a>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Enter">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Compared to the video, you are missing a `padding: 50px 40px;` in the `.form` part.

Try replacing your `.form` css with this:

```
.form {
    position: absolute;
    inset: 3px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    background: #343745;
    z-index: 10;
    padding: 50px 40px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

UPDATE: furthermore, there is an issue with the `<h4>` tag which is opened twice. Maybe you should have `<h4>Log In</h4>`.